# Error in static development while creating application from geonode template

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, geoserver

I created a django application which follows geonode template from these commands

**django-admin.py startproject  --template=https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-project/archive/master.zip -epy,rst

sudo pip install -e **

The django server is running but the problem is that the application cannot access or find css, js and images which geonode development version uses. 
I had to manually copy and paste these files from geonode's static folder. It still requires some more resources

I am using **Mac OS X 10.9.1**

Can anyone please tell me how to access geonode's static files from your application which uses geonode template on **Mac**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template in geonode-project is not up to date with geonode master (aka 2.4dev).

You should use a template adapted for v2.4 [like this fork of simod](https://github.com/simod/geonode-project/tree/2.4).

To launch a dev server once the template is installed just cd to the folder and launch:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

To "install" your new template project

```
python setup.py install
```

BTW, usually is better configure a virtualenv to develop python apps and not use `sudo`